# How do you properly use a Console.Readline() in a loop with string integer?

Tags: c#

I'm baby-new to c# and building a project on mental health with multiple objects - starting with loops. Is there more tactful way to approach this code?
I ran basic code input via following:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("How are you feeling (1-bad to 5 great)?");
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(" Mood: " + userInput);        
if (! Int32.TryParse(userInput, out x))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Invalid data input");
}
else if (x == 1)
{
   Console.WriteLine(" very low.");    
}
else if (x == 2)
{
   Console.WriteLine(" low.");
}
else if (x == 3)
{
   Console.WriteLine(" average.");
}
else if (x == 4)
{
   Console.WriteLine(" good.");
}
else if (x == 5)
{
   Console.WriteLine(" very good.");
}
```

Comment: Use a switch-case structure instead of a else if.

Comment: A switch statement might be more concise for this. You could also use a `Dictionary<int, string>` or `Dictionary<string, string>` if you're just mapping a few in->out values.

Answer (score 1):

try this, it is more compact code

```
    var invalidData = false;
    var x = 0;
    var moods = new string[] { " very low.", " low.", " average.", " good.", " very good." };
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How are you feeling(1 - bad to 5 great)?");
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" Mood: " + userInput);
        if (!Int32.TryParse(userInput, out x) || x < 1 || x > 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid data input");
            invalidData = true;
        }
        else invalidData = false;
    }
    while (invalidData);

    Console.WriteLine(moods[x-1]);
```